# how do I arrange my gradepoint table customizingly?help me to align

Tags: exam, gradetable

I am having 28 questions in my question paper and I have spilited into 3 sections, How do I make my grade table so that my grade table should contains, 
 And i need the section must be center aligned. help me to align.

The first section points,

table

The second section points,

table

The third section points,

table

May be like this,

[image: this]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\title{FULL BOOSTER TEST}
\author{}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\section{Part-A}
\question[3] this is first,

\question [3] this is second,

\question[3] theis is third,

\vdots\vdots

\section*{Part-B}

\question[4] this is not fourth question but may 15 th question.

\question [4] \ldots

\question[4] \vdots

\section*{Part-C}

\question[6] this is not 7th question rather  22 nd question.


\question[6] \ldots
\newpage
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

[image: sectioning]

Comment: Kindly give codes, which will split the table as shown in section A of my drawings... I need it for the question paper which has large number of questions in a sections...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\begingradingrange` and `\endgradingrange` to specify each sections questions. Then use `\partialgradetable` to create your gradetabels:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-1in}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}}

\title{FULL BOOSTER TEST\vspace*{-1.5cm}}
\author{}
\date{\today\vspace*{-.5cm}}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \begin{questions}

        \section*{Part-A}

            \begingradingrange{a1}
                \question[3] this is first,
                \question[3] this is second,
                \question[3] this is third,
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
            \endgradingrange{a1}

            \begingradingrange{a2}
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
            \endgradingrange{a2}

        \section*{Part-B}

            \begingradingrange{b}
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
            \endgradingrange{b}

        \section*{Part-C}

            \begingradingrange{c}
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
                \question[6] \ldots
            \endgradingrange{c}

    \end{questions}

    \maketitle

    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.6cm}p{1.5cm}}
        \vspace{5pt}
        Marks secured
        &
        \vspace{0pt}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (0,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (1.5,0) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{-1cm}

    \section*{\centering Section-A}
        \partialgradetable{a1}[h][questions]

        \vspace*{.5cm}

        \noindent\partialgradetable{a2}[h][questions]

    \section*{\centering Section-B}
        \partialgradetable{b}[h][questions]

    \section*{\centering Section-C}
        \partialgradetable{c}[h][questions]

    \vfill

    \noindent\underline{Remarks:}

    \vspace*{2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much.. kindly check my section title in question paper is not in center alignment...@Maarten

Comment: `\section*{Part-A}` gives you left alignment; `\section*{\centering Part-A}` gives you centered alignment.